# Conditionally instantiating correct subclasses?

Tags: php, class, polymorphism, subclass, abstract

Is there a correct way to conditionally instantiate certain subclasses?

For example, I have a `User` class that includes the method `get_membership()` which will return a subclass based on the type of membership it is passed. I'm currently using a switch statement to return the correct subclass, however I'm not convinced this is the best approach.

Short example of what I' working with:

```
class User
{
  public $user_id;
  public function __construct( $user_id )
  {
   $this->user_id = $user_id;
  }
  public function get_membership( $membership_type = 'annual' ) 
  {
   switch( $membership_type )
   {
     case 'annual':
     return new AnnualMembership( $this->user_id );
     break;

     case 'monthly':
     return new MonthlyMembership( $this->user_id );
     break;
   }
  }
}

abstract class UserMembership
{
  protected $user_id;
  protected $length_in_days;

  public function __construct( $user_id )
  {
    $this->user_id = $user_id;
    $this->setup();
  }

  abstract protected function get_length_in_days();
  abstract protected function setup();

}

class AnnualMembership extends UserMembership
{
  public function setup() {
   $this->length_in_days = 365;
  }

  public function get_length_in_days()
  {
    return $this->length_in_days;
  }
}

class MonthlyMembership extends UserMembership
{
  public function setup() {
   $this->length_in_days = 30;
  }

  public function get_length_in_days()
  {
    return $this->length_in_days;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's OK to conditionally instantiate the right subclass, though usually it is advised to separate this logic into a different class/method, called a [`factory`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern). In fact, this is a very common [`design pattern`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern).

Comment: Thanks @dean-fenster, what I thought but wasn't sure.